# How do I install a 2 gang low voltage bracket?

Tags: drywall, switch, brackets

Purchased varying 1 gang and 2 gang low voltage screw-in type brackets as seen [here](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=105&cp_id=10425&cs_id=1042507&p_id=7019&seq=1&format=1#largeimage).

Upon inspection they appeared to simply sit in the wall with the the screws being screwed into the side of the dry wall; however that seems incorrect as now having seen this [image](http://www.cepro.com/arlington/product/lvs1_mounting_bracket_fo_class_2_low_voltage_wiring/).

Confusion has surfaced as the end goal is to install [this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=105&cp_id=10425&cs_id=1042505&p_id=4001&seq=1&format=1#largeimage) and since this is an existing installation my concern is that I might have purchased a bracket geared towards a new install.

So...how do I install these brackets in an exiting drywall installation without having to use a stud or should I use a different type of brackets?

If somebody wants to add a bracket tag and re-tag the question that would be great.

**EDIT:**

Looks like [this](http://www.monoprice.com/products/product.asp?c_id=105&cp_id=10425&cs_id=1042507&p_id=7013&seq=1&format=2) is what I should have purchased; will await confirmation from the experts.

Comment: yep, you answered your own question. Old work rings or boxes are the way to go. just cut the hole, insert the ring and turn the tabs into place and tighten, done!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question.

The first type of mount is for screwing into a stud, the second is for drywall/plasterboard.

You can still use the first type though.

Cut the hole for the switch in the drywall and then cut a length of batten just longer that the hole. Then fix this to one side of the hole inside the cavity. This is the tricky bit as you might end up having to screw into the batten through the drywall, which is going to leave you with a couple of screw heads to cover. If you can use an adhesive that should work as the bracket and light switch aren't very heavy.

Once the batten is firmly secured, fix the batten as illustrated on the web page.

However, I would first see if you can arrange an exchange.

Comment: Yep...got the ones geared for drywall.

Answer (score 1):

As Chris mentions, you answered your own question.  However, I think Home Depot, and probably the other major stores, have this for much less in the form of a metal bracket that you install with a pair of pliers and modular wall plates for various A/V, networking, and phone plugs.  I've installed them all over the house here.  All you need is a drywall saw, small rasp, and a pair of pliers to install the bracket (I use a pair of channel lock pliers because the angle on the pliers makes it easy to get into the wall and make a tight attachment).

---

Edit, here are some links to the system.  Buying in bulk in at the store I think was cheaper than this:

Mounting bracket, the two wings fold up/down into the wall to hold the bracket in place.  You could just hand tighten, but a pair of pliers gets  a good fit:

http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100195825/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053

4 module plate, they have them from 1 to 8 modules:

http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100092855/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053

Sample module for ethernet wiring:

http://www.homedepot.com/h_d1/N-5yc1v/R-100195386/h_d2/ProductDisplay?langId=-1&storeId=10051&catalogId=10053

Like I say, check in store and specifically the bulk packages (10+).  I only bring this up because I see the monoprice links and in this case, I'm not sure they are cheaper.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I have yet to find anything from Monoprice to be ore expensive then that of the big box stores; such as Home Depot or Lowes. I certainly use them in a crunch though...

Comment: For the same item, I'm pretty sure Monoprice would be better.  For a different item that does the same thing, it doesn't hurt to shop around.